# What does the Local close error mean sending a https call using jetty http client?

Tags: java, jetty

I am getting the following error when making a http call over ssl with jetty http client with both client certificates and server authentication.

```
java.io.EOFException: local close
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.close(HttpConnection.java:651)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

In response to comments adding full error:

```
FAILED: testNucleusOnline
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Request failed exchange status:9 HTTP:0
at com.XXX.XXXX.IAbstractOperation.get(IAbstractOperation.java:26)
at com.XXX.XXXX.IAbstractOperation.get(IAbstractOperation.java:14)
at com.XXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX(XXXXXX.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:110)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
```

and code with some hidding:

```
    IAbstractOperation iAbstract = new IAbstractOperation();
    iAbstract.setURL(availabilityUrl);
    iAbstract.setMethod("GET");


    if (iAbstract.startsWith("https:")) {
        iAbstract.setScheme(HttpSchemes.HTTPS_BUFFER);
    }

    httpClient.send(iAbstract);
    return iAbstract;
```

Comment: It would help if you put your connection code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it means the conversation has been shutdown in the middle of the exchange of SSL.  Here is the code:

```
 public void close() throws IOException
 {
     //if there is a live, unfinished exchange, set its status to be
     //excepted and wake up anyone waiting on waitForDone()

     if (_exchange != null && !_exchange.isDone())
     {
         switch (_exchange.getStatus())
         {
             case HttpExchange.STATUS_CANCELLED:
             case HttpExchange.STATUS_CANCELLING:
             case HttpExchange.STATUS_COMPLETED:
             case HttpExchange.STATUS_EXCEPTED:
             case HttpExchange.STATUS_EXPIRED:
                 break;
             default:
                 _exchange.setStatus(HttpExchange.STATUS_EXCEPTED);
                 _exchange.getEventListener().onException(new EOFException("local close"));
         }
     } 
     _endp.close();
 }
```

Quite possibly shutting down the connection before it's done with the SSL handshake is what I interpret.  I don't see your code on the stacktrace so I'm a little confused about where this is taking place (client end or server end).